# understanding the last command

Tags: networking

Iv'e just done a `last` command and am looking through the results, and came across these two:

```
pi       pts/0        192.168.1.3      Tue Feb  4 18:55 - crash  (00:-37)
pi       pts/0        192.168.1.3      Tue Feb  4 22:42 - down   (00:16)
```

These ips aren't either of my pis on the network, so i'm guessing they'e my Laptop. The bit i'm interested in is the "**crash**","**down** and "**pts/o**". Could someone please explain what these are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the first hit I get when I search for this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/when-using-the-last-command-in-linux-what-does-crash-and-down-mean-161464/

According to that link, "down" means a regular logout, and "crash" means that it couldn't find a logout entry so it assumes that it crashed at the given time.  Maybe you pulled the power or something.

tty is a terminal, pts is apparently a "pseudoterminal", not sure what that means, but pts/0 is therefore pseudoterminal number zero.  Also, `man last` is your friend.

Maybe try `-d` as a parameter to `last` to get it to show the hostname for 192.168.1.3, otherwise use something like `ifconfig` on your laptop to confirm that it has that IP address.